# Webserver behind NAT

Tags: webserver, nat, domain-name

My setup: home router with public dynamic IP, PC with W10, I installed a VMware, and under it a LAMP Linux web server behind NAT.I use dyndns to reach the PC from outside (internet). I made a port forward tunneling towards the virtual machine, so I can reach the website with the localhost:8080 My question: I purchased a WordPress domain name but I want to use my own virtual web server. What I have to do to point my new WordPress domain name to my web server?
Update_01:Thanks the first answer. I try to be more specific. On the wordpress management site (dashboard) the URL now is localhost:8080 but here should be the recently registered wordpress domain name "example.com". But if I replace it I can not reach the site because there is no name resolution (DNS). The question still the same, how can I integrate the new wordpress domain name into the system.
Do I have to edit the apache config file or the wp config file or the DNS domain settings to connect my dyndns domain name with the new wordpress domain name?  My aim is to reach my site from the internet with the registered new wordpress domain name, not with the dyndns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look up the specific instructions for your firewall / router, but typically you'll need two rules.

First, the firewall rule allowing traffic through the port you want to use (80 and 443 for HTTP and HTTPS)

Second, you'll need NAT rule(s) to have your router point traffic sent to your static WAN IP to go to the private LAN IP of your web server. You should set your local web server to have a static IP to avoid problems.

Most firewalls / routers allow all outgoing traffic, but in case yours doesn't, set a rule there.